# random GridView with Images

Tags: java, android

I want to create a DayDream for my App and i want a Wall of images but i dont know how to randomize the images.

I want that some images are (2 times) bigger than other images and the other images are around them, all random. Is there a simple way to do this?
The Images are saved dynamically in a ArrayList of ImageViews before they will be loaded into the GridView.

Currently i have a simple Horizontal Layout which gets filled with ImageViews, but this is way too simple and won't fill the complete screen...

I have no point where i could start, any help would be fine!

Comment: You can use the [`Random`-class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) for a random-[primitive]-generator. There is also [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to shuffle a collection (like an ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can do that with a GridView. You're essentially looking to do a `TableView` and specify how many columns an item can take up. Alternatively, with some fiddling, you may be able to achieve what you want with a `RelativeLayout`.

For both `TableView` and `RelativeLayout` you'll have to write your own adapters to put the content in the views.

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/quiltview-library/ or
http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/
as far as i know quiltview is created randomly every time, so maybe u should go with that.